# How to use JOOQ Java Generator includes and excludes

Tags: jooq

The JOOQ Java code generation tools uses regular expressions defined in the includes and excludes elements to control what is generated. I cant find an explanation of what the schema structure is that these expressions are run against.

I want to have the ability to exclude specific databases in the server as well as tables by prefix or specifically.

Simple examples:

- Given a SQL server with two DBs 'A' and 'B', how do I instruct JOOQ to only generate for tables in DB 'A'?
- How do in instruct JOOQ to only generate for tables starting with the prefix "qtbl"?

It would be great if there were some example use cases available showing some simple common configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The [jOOQ manual section about includes and excludes](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-includes-excludes/), as well as a few other sections that explain the code generator's usage of regular expressions to match identifier establishes that the code generator will always try to:

- Match fully qualified identifiers
- Match unqualified identifiers

Or, if you're using jOOQ 3.12+ and did not turn off `<regexMatchesPartialQualification/>`:

- Match partially qualified identifiers (see [#7947](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7947))

For example:

```xml
<excludes>
  (?i:                      # Using case insensitive regex for the example
       database_prefix.*?\. # Match a catalog prefix prior to the qualifying "."
       .*?\.                # You don't seem to care about schema names, so match them all
       table_prefix.*?      # Match a table prefix at the end of the identifier
  )
</excludes>
```

In addition to the above, if you want to exclude specific databases ("catalogs") from being generated without pattern matching, you'll get even better results if you specify your `<inputCatalog>A</inputCatalog>`. See also the [manual's section about schema mapping](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/).

Benefits include a much faster code generation, because only that catalog will be searched for objects to generate, prior to excluding them again using regular expressions. So, your configuration could be this:

```xml
<!-- Include only database A -->
<inputCatalog>A</inputCatalog>

<!-- Include only tables with this (unqualified) prefix -->
<includes>qtbl.*</includes>
```